# Inline-block divs not aligning horizontally

Tags: html, css

I have a project where I need to align certain elements just so. For whatever reason, it's not working. My HTML:

```
<div class="heading">
    <h1>Exotic <strong>Travel</strong></h1>
        <div class="left">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.htm">homepage</a></li>
            <br>
            <li><a href="aboutus.htm">about us</a></li>
            <br>
            <li><a href="destination.htm">destinations</a></li>
            <br>
            <li><a href="booking.htm">book a ticket</a></li>
            <br>
            <li><a href="contact.htm">contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    <div class="rightimg">
            <img src="banner.jpg" alt="Beachside Hotel" />
    </div>
    <div class="righttext"> 
            <h2>The Perfect Destination</h2>
    </div>

</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url(sky.jpg);
    font-family: "Verdana", sans serif;
    }

h1 {
    font-family: "Calibri Light", sans serif;
    color: gray;
    }

h2 {
    background-color: green;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width:  750px;
    }

a  {
    color: white;
    margin: 4px;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

.left{
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width: 350px;
    }

.heading {
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 1000px;
    }


.righttext {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    height: 60px;
    width: 750px;
    }

.rightimg {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 750px;
    }
```

This SHOULD be working, based on other similar examples I've seen on  the site, but it's not taking. Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it intentional that the left div, and right text div is a part of the heading div? This doesn't seem right to me. In addition you seem to have an issue using fixed width

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking? Do you mean because I have divs nested inside of divs?

Comment: Yes, the nested divs are disturbing the other divs, and thusly you can not place them according to your wishes...

Answer (score 2):

I think you are breaking it with your fixed widths, I used 40% width on the left and righttext and that seemed to get everything inline:

```
.left{
background-color: red;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
height: 200px;
width: 40%;
}

.righttext {
display: inline-block;
float: right;
height: 60px;
width: 40%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bkyLojx4/

Also as an fyi br tags are not valid in a ul. Rather use css to handle the styling of the list.

Comment: Changing the fixed widths to percentages doesn't change anything. I need it to look almost exactly like this example (http://jsfiddle.net/Lmntv6am/7/), only reversed with the two stacked columns on the right instead of the left.

Comment: Okay, maybe this is more what you are looking for:
https://jsfiddle.net/Iconiq/tvg8d5zz/

I removed the vertical aligns, and added a second container.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have the elements at a fixed width which means the combined width of all 3 elements is more than the space available. Try using a percentile widths for adaptive design or adjusting it to the resolution you want to support.

Comment: That doesnt seem to change anything: